# Can the mgconsole output style be changed to CSV like format?

Tags: memgraphdb

When I run `MATCH (n)-[e]->(m) RETURN n, e, m;` I get the output similar to this:

```
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| n                              | e                              | m                              |
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| (:User {id: "0", name: "0"})   | [:FRIENDS_WITH]                | (:User {id: "1", name: "1"})   |
| (:User {id: "0", name: "0"})   | [:FRIENDS_WITH]                | (:User {id: "2", name: "2"})   |
| (:User {id: "1", name: "1"})   | [:FRIENDS_WITH]                | (:User {id: "2", name: "2"})   |
| (:User {id: "0", name: "0"})   | [:FRIENDS_WITH]                | (:User {id: "3", name: "3"})   |
| (:User {id: "1", name: "1"})   | [:FRIENDS_WITH]                | (:User {id: "3", name: "3"})   |
| (:User {id: "2", name: "2"})   | [:FRIENDS_WITH]                | (:User {id: "3", name: "3"})   |
| (:User {id: "0", name: "0"})   | [:FRIENDS_WITH]                | (:User {id: "4", name: "4"})   |
| (:User {id: "0", name: "0"})   | [:FRIENDS_WITH]                | (:User {id: "5", name: "5"})   |
| (:User {id: "0", name: "0"})   | [:FRIENDS_WITH]                | (:User {id: "6", name: "6"})   |
| (:User {id: "4", name: "4"})   | [:FRIENDS_WITH]                | (:User {id: "6", name: "6"})   |
| (:User {id: "5", name: "5"})   | [:FRIENDS_WITH]                | (:User {id: "6", name: "6"})   |
| (:User {id: "0", name: "0"})   | [:FRIENDS_WITH]                | (:User {id: "7", name: "7"})   |
| (:User {id: "1", name: "1"})   | [:FRIENDS_WITH]                | (:User {id: "7", name: "7"})   |
| (:User {id: "2", name: "2"})   | [:FRIENDS_WITH]                | (:User {id: "7", 
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

I have a awk onliner that I use for conversion, `awk -F'[{|}]' 'BEGIN { OFS=","; print "n,e,m" } NF > 2 { print $2, $4, $6 }' input.txt > output.csv`, but I'd like to skip this step if possible. Can the `mgconsole` output be directly in CSV format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start `mgconsole` with the flag `-output_format`. This flag can be `csv` or `tabular`.